# How do you square an entire logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can $(\log_y x)^2$ be simplified further, or be made easier to work with? Can you say that $(\log_y x)^2 = 2\log_y x$?

Comment: Right, it is not. Your logarithm is a number, $\log_y(x)$, and squaring it means multiplying that number by itself.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: $(\log_yx)^2$ is as simple as it gets.

Comment: It’s the same as $\log_y\left( x^{\log_y(x)}\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $(\log_y x)^2$ (sometimes written $\log_y^2 x$) cannot be simplified by bringing the 2 down as a coefficient. In other words,
$$(\log_y x)^2 \neq 2 \log_y x.$$

You may write $(\log_y x )^2 = (\log_y x) ( \log_y x)$.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, the change of base formula may also be useful, that is

$$(\log_y x)^2= \left (\frac{\log x}{\log y}\right )^2  $$
where the logarithms here may be taken to any base (as long as the base in the numerator and denominator is the same).

The case when you can make the exponent into a coefficient is when the *argument* of the logarithm is being raised to a power:
For example
$$ \log_y(x^2) = 2 \log_y (x)\ \textrm{for} \ x>0.$$

Comment: $\log_yx^2\neq2\log_yx$. Try $x=-1$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Good catch! Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my answer accordingly.